# Bootstrap navbar displays as regular <li>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to follow the default bootstrap tutorial on W3 to create a page that has a navbar in the header. My navbar appears, but not as expected. The dots for the li tag are still appearing, and they are right on top of each other.

[image: The navbar appearance.]

I am not certain what is causing this. Here is the HTML for the page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
        <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js") %>
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js") %>
        <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css") %>
        <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css") %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="site-title"><%: Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home") %></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <section id="login">
                        <%: Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") %>
                    </section>                    

                </div>
            </div>                    
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header"></div>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="menu">
                            <li class="active"><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") %></li>
                            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %></li>
                            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home") %></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>     
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FeaturedContent" runat="server" />
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptsSection" runat="server" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I am attempting this in Chrome and Firefox, both with the same results. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `<ul class="navbar-nav" id="menu">` to `<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">` (add the `nav` class) and you shouldn't need these extra divs around the `ul`. See the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

This is what you have:

```
<div>
  <ul class="navbar-nav" id="menu">
    <li class="active">
      <%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%: Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home") %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is what you can change it to. See working Snippet.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p class="site-title">
          LOGO
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <section id="login">
          LOGIN
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: This was definitely the most thorough and accurate answer. I actually discovered that the parent div was the main culprit in the appearance issue. No change to the CSS was necessary. Thank you for the response, accepted as still the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the bullets for the 'li' tags, which can be usually removed using CSS as

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS code in your *.css file, or inside `style` tag in `header`:

```
.navbar-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar-nav li {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: This is generally doing what I need it to do. However, the bar items still appear as individual links (the area isn't highlighting) and the active selection is going beyond the bar. I'm using the default bootstrap 3.3.6 css. Should this not be handled by bootstrap already?

Comment: Depends, what css you use with the bootstrap. Please, provide the link, or full html page+css code, then I can help you